# Read Extension of a file in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to read the extension of a file which is coming from a server using web services in Angular 6.

I am able to read the extensions of the file like `myFile.png` using `filename.split('.').pop();` method and using `filename.slice((filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);` method.

but my problem is the file link that is coming from the server is very long in length and it is a downloadable link so that from that link we can download the actual file.

**Sample link format is as follows:** http://myserver.data.com/data/service/auth/yt.content.ContentHttp/viewContent/myfile.png?u8&HttpOperationItem=yt.content.ApplicationData%3A342376&ofn=myfile.png&ContentHolder=yt.flow.forum.data%3A342370&forceDownload=true

In the above link, I want to read the extension of the file which is just before the `(?)` operator. and the operator`(?)` is coming only once in the link. so that I can identified that the extension of the file is placed just before the `(?)` operator.

can anyone help to get the extension of the file using Angular 6.

Comment: can try this- `filename.split('?')[0].split('.').pop();`

Comment: @ashishpal it is working thank you so much, brother. can you post your answer in the comment so that I can accept the solution.

Comment: welcome,  yes sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `?` will come only once so can split with `?` and then select first element and again split with `.` and get last element.

```
filename.split('?')[0].split('.').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex. Such as : `viewContent\/\w+.([\w\d]+)`

Here is an example of *how to use the regex*:

```
const regex = /viewContent\/\w+.([\w\d]+)/gm;
const str = `http://myserver.data.com/data/service/auth/yt.content.ContentHttp/viewContent/myfile.png?u8&HttpOperationItem=yt.content.ApplicationData%3A342376&ofn=myfile.png&ContentHolder=yt.flow.forum.data%3A342370&forceDownload=true`;

regex.exec(str)) !== null
```